# How do you find solutions to the equation $\frac{x}{y^\frac{x}{y}} = 1$, which involves the Lambert W function?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, logarithms, lambert-w

How do you solve for $x$ in the following equation:

$$
\frac{x}{y^\frac{x}{y}} = 1
$$

By graphing it, I know there are two real solutions. I tried doing it in the following way:

$$
x = y^\frac{x}{y} \\
\ln x = \ln y^\frac{x}{y} \\
\ln x = \frac{x}{y} \ln y \\
\frac{\ln x}{x} = \frac{\ln y}{y} \\
\int \frac{\ln x}{x} dx = \int \frac{\ln y}{y} dy \\
\frac{\ln^2 x}{2} = \frac{\ln^2 y}{2} \\
\ln^2 x = \ln^2 y \\
\ln x = \pm \sqrt{\ln^2 y} \\
x = e^{\pm \sqrt{\ln^2 y}}
$$

But this is only half correct, with the positive sign, where we obtain $x = y$. The negative sign is incorrect. Where did I go wrong? I do realize I left out the $+ C$ when taking the integral, but is that why? I put this into Wolfram Alpha and the other solution is in terms of the Lambert W function. I must admit I have never worked with the Lambert W function before. I've been doing a bit of research on it and trying to understand it. Can anyone explain it to me? As in, how do you get the Lambert W function from the equation above? Also, I read on Wikipedia that the Lambert W function cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions. So, how do you compute its actual value? Is there a table somewhere? What I'm more interested in is the difference between the two solutions for $x$ for a fixed $y$. Any feedback would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall the definition of Lambert W ... $ue^u = v \Longleftrightarrow u=W(v)$.  In this case:
\begin{align}
\frac{x}{y^{x/y}} &= 1
\\
x &= y^{x/y}
\\
x &= \exp \left(\frac{x}{y}\ln y\right)
\\
-\frac{x}{y}\ln y &= \exp \left(\frac{x}{y}\ln y\right)\frac{-\ln y}{y}
\\
-\frac{x}{y}\ln y \exp \left(-\frac{x}{y}\ln y\right)&= \frac{-\ln y}{y}
\\
-\frac{x}{y}\ln y &= W\left(\frac{-\ln y}{y}\right)
\\
x &= -\frac{y}{\ln y}W\left(\frac{-\ln y}{y}\right)
\end{align}

Here are the real graphs: $W_0$ (blue) and $W_{-1}$ (red)

[image: graph]

---

Example:  For $y=2$, we have
$$
x = -\frac{2}{\ln 2}W_0\left(\frac{-\ln 2}{2}\right) = 2
$$
or
$$
x = -\frac{2}{\ln 2}W_{-1}\left(\frac{-\ln 2}{2}\right) = 4
$$
I got these numerically from Maple.  But
the two real values $u=W(v)$ are the two solutions of $ue^u = v$.  So write
$$
x=-\frac{2}{\ln 2}W\left(\frac{-\ln 2}{2}\right)
\\
\Longleftrightarrow\quad x\exp\left(-\frac{x \ln 2}{2}\right)=1
$$
Two solutions of this are $x=2$ and $x=4$, easily checked.

Comment: The two graphs are $$x = -\frac{y}{\ln y}W_0\left(\frac{-\ln y}{y}\right)\quad\text{and}\quad x = -\frac{y}{\ln y}W_{-1}\left(\frac{-\ln y}{y}\right)$$ Why do you think it is solvable without a computer?  Of course, when we examine $x/y^{x/y} = 1$ we can see that $x=y$ is one solution.  But I see no simple computation for the other solution.

Comment: Another remark:  there has been a lot written about the equation $x^y = y^x$, which is essentially the same problem as yours.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate your help! :)